# php str_replace issue with url(s)

Tags: php

I have this very simple php line ($html contains some not so long text, lets say around 3000 characters):

```
$html = str_replace('href="http://www.myurl.com', 'href="http://subdomain.myurl.com', $html);
```

it is so simple that I can't understand why it doens't work, maybe some issue with '//'?

any help appreciated

Comment: Why's here `\"`? You try to escape something?

Comment: oh sorry I made a lot of attempts, I update the question

Comment: What _it doens't work_ mean here?

Comment: The code you gave in the question seems to work for me, what's not working at your side?

Comment: @user3174311 what is the desired outcome?

Comment: https://eval.in/624924 Your script works.

Comment: this code work fine with me :O

Comment: Does the protocol vary between `//`, `http://`, and/or `https://`?

Answer (score 0):

Although, `str_replace()` is relatively a bit faster in comparison to `preg_replace()`; since the content of your HTML String is unknown to us at this Time, one may suggest using `preg_replace()` instead. This would be how:

```
<?php


    $html   = "Lorem ipsum dolor enim purus, <a href='http://www.myurl.com/friendly-url-1/1'>sit amet</a> ";
    $html  .= "sed nascetur, ac et, habitasse adipiscing <a href='http://www.myurl.com/friendly-url-2/2'>velit elementum</a>, ";
    $html  .= "mauris nisi eros <a href='http://www.myurl.com/'>turpis aliquam</a> lorem.";

    $rx     = "#(href=['\"])(http[s]?:\/\/)?(www.)?(myurl\.com)#sim";
    $rpl    = "$1$2subdomain.$4";
    $html   = preg_replace($rx, $rpl,  $html);
```

You may (if you choose) [try out a simulated Example](https://eval.in/624930)...